# Ag-grid - full screen chart range

Tags: charts, range, ag-grid, panel

In the demo below, right click on any line, then Chart Range and click on any mode. A panel will open. Is this panel possible to maximize in full screen?
https://ag-grid.com/example

Comment: Do you mean "Panel should be opened in full screen by default"

Comment: That's right. Or when click to resize.